# PHP curl - get response from API

Tags: php, curl, get

So, I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes PHP curl/json. I've made pretty good progress with the integration of the Pinpayments.com hosted fields payment form in to my new site. (This module code is built in Drupal, not that should affect what I need to do.)

What I need to do is pull the relevant message from the response from pinpayments when a payment is sucessful or a payment is declined. At present the payment form I have does submit the payment as it shows up on my pinpayments dashboard - but I can't figure out how to display an error message when the card is declined.

This is the code I have at present that means I can post the form:

```
<?php



namespace Drupal\drupalup_simple_form\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;

/**
 * Our simple form class.
 */
class SimpleAjaxForm extends FormBase {



  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'payment_form';
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#attributes'] = array('id' => array('payment_form'));


    $form['publishkey'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Key',
      '#id' => 'card_token',
      '#value' => 'pk_wkHM76EknXUavjrEYZlvNQ'
    ];

    $form['address_line1'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Address line 1',
      '#id' => 'address_line1'
    ];
      $form['address_line2'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Address line 2',
      '#id' => 'address_line2'
    ];
      $form['address_city'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'City',
      '#id' => 'address_city'
    ];
      $form['address_postcode'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Postcode',
      '#id' => 'address_postcode'
    ];
      $form['address_state'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'State',
      '#id' => 'address_state'
    ];
      $form['address_country'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Country',
      '#id' => 'address_country'
    ];



    $form['name'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div id="name"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the "name" field --></div>',
    ];
    $form['errors_for_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_name">&nbsp;</div>',
    ];


    $form['number'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div id="number"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the "number" field --></div>',
    ];
    $form['errors_for_number'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_number">&nbsp;</div>',
    ];


    $form['cvc'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div id="cvc"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the "cvc" field --></div>',
    ];
    $form['errors_for_cvc'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_cvc">&nbsp;</div',
    ];


    $form['expiry'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div id="expiry"><!-- Hosted Fields will populate this with the "expiry" field --></div>',
    ];  
    $form['errors_for_expiry'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="error_message" id="errors_for_expiry">&nbsp;</div>',
    ];  

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => 'Submit'
    ];

    return $form;
  }



  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

}

$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://test-api.pinpayments.com/1/charges');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "amount=500&currency=AUD&description=test charge&email=roland@pinpayments.com&ip_address=203.192.1.172&card[number]=4100000000000001&card[expiry_month]=05&card[expiry_year]=2021&card[cvc]=123&card[name]=TIGER WOODS&card[address_line1]=$_POST[address_line1]&card[address_line2]=&card[address_city]=$_POST[address_city]&card[address_postcode]=$_POST[address_postcode]&card[address_state]= $_POST[address_state]&card[address_country]=$_POST[address_country]&metadata[OrderNumber]=123456&metadata[CustomerName]=Roland Robot");



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'REMOVED MY SECRET KEY' . ':' . '');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

How do I do a 'GET' so that if the payment is declined I'm somehow able to show this to the user?

```
{
  "error": "card_declined",
  "error_description": "The card was declined",
  "charge_token": "ch_lfUYEBK14zotCTykezJkfg"
}
```

https://pinpayments.com/developers/api-reference/charges

Answer (score 0):

```
$token = "xyz";

$error = array(
    "error" => "card_declined",
    "error_description" => "The card was declined",
    "charge_token"=> $token
    );

echo(json_encode($error,true));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's giving me - unexpected ":" for the three output lines i.e. "error":"card_declined",

Comment: The text below the "output" comment was the result of the code and didn't need to be used ... See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it just inserts the array before the <doctype>:

{"error":"card_declined","error_description":"The card was declined","charge_token":""}<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: If you don't want the output to appear on the page, replace your "echo" with a "return".

Comment: That's the thing - I want the error message to display on the screen to the user that their payment has been declined.

Comment: Okay, so now the problem is different. I recommend you create a new question to not mix the subjects polluting this post.

Comment: Anyway, if the response from this php code will be displayed on your front-end php/html page, check that the php code is being called at the correct point in front-end.

If this code is going to be read at an API endpoint, change echo to return, and retrieve the result with a GET method.